# iphone: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone

I am new to objective C, So maybe there is some basic thing that I am missing about selectors. I would like to understand the basic concept behind this error as I have not found an general error reference.

I am getting this error when using:

```
[CloseButton addTarget:PageContents action:@selector(CloseButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and then later:

```
- (void)CloseButtonPressed:(id)sender{
   UIAlertView *someError = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Comment" message: @"hello" delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
   [someError show];
   [someError release];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A couple suggestions that will help your code follow writing conventions used by all Objective C applications, and make your code more easily readable to others:

1. Object instances should be lower case, i.e. `closeButton` and not `CloseButton`, and `pageContents`, not `PageContents`
2. Method names should be lower case, i.e. `-closeButtonPressed:` and not `-CloseButtonPressed:`

To answer your question, you need to fix the action you are adding:

```
[CloseButton addTarget:PageContents action:@selector(CloseButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

That colon character (`:`) makes sure the `sender` gets through to `-CloseButtonPressed:`

Answer (score 0):

As CloseButtonPressed takes parameter you should create selector using: `@selector(CloseButtonPressed:)`